# how can I combine these lines

Tags: bash, shell, debian

How can I combine these lines (NOTE: this is just an excerpt from a much larger file):

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip proxy-arp
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.202
 no ip proxy-arp
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.358
 no ip proxy-arp
interface FastEthernet0/0/1.26
 no ip proxy-arp
interface GigabitEthernet0/0
 no ip proxy-arp
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.202
 no ip proxy-arp
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.358
 no ip proxy-arp
interface FastEthernet0/0/1.26
 no ip proxy-arp
interface Loopback0
 no ip proxy-arp
interface Loopback1
 no ip proxy-arp
interface Loopback26
 no ip proxy-arp
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0
 no ip proxy-arp
```

so that they resemble this:

```
interface GigabitEthernet0/0 | no ip proxy-arp
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.202 | no ip proxy-arp
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.358 | no ip proxy-arp
interface FastEthernet0/0/1.26 | no ip proxy-arp
interface GigabitEthernet0/0 | no ip proxy-arp
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.202 | no ip proxy-arp
interface GigabitEthernet0/0.358 | no ip proxy-arp
interface FastEthernet0/0/1.26 | no ip proxy-arp
interface Loopback0 | no ip proxy-arp
interface Loopback1 | no ip proxy-arp
interface Loopback26 | no ip proxy-arp
interface GigabitEthernet0/0/0 | no ip proxy-arp
```

I've tried a few different solutions that I have found online, but none of them seem to work correctly for my situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this sed one-liner:

```
sed 'N;s/\n/ | /;s/\r//g' file.txt
```

Comment: If you specifically want to remove space(s) before `no ip`, change `'N;s/\n/ | /'` to `'N;s/\n */ | /'`

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I got the following when I ran this command: | no ip proxy-arpEthernet0/0 (all of the lines are in that format)

Comment: You have saved your test file in CRLF format... Check the edit.

Answer (score 5):

paste can do it:

```
paste -d '|' - - < file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 awk '{printf "%s%s",$0,(NR%2?"|":"\n")}' file
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your help. I got the following when I ran this command:
| no ip proxy-arpEthernet0/0

(all of the lines are in that format)

Comment: @lacrosse1991 I run the command with your example, it gave the same output in your question....

Comment: hello, anishsane mentioned that the file was in CRLF format, works now, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
while IFS= read line1 && IFS= read line2; do
    printf "%s | %s\n" "$line1" "$line2"
done < file.txt
```